# R number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length for creating list

Tags: r, list, for-loop, append

Hi I am trying to create a list where each index will store different data based on matching condition.I have following data:

```
col1    col2    col3
500x    high    9.07
5x      low     23.6
50x     medium  11.64
500x    high    8.24
5x      low     35.17
50x     medium  12.82
```

I have following R script:

```
somelist<-list()
tempinfo<-("500x","50x","5x")
for(k in seq(from=1,to=nrow(dataset),by=3)){
    for(y in 0:2){
        if (any(as.character(dataset[,1][k+y]) == tempinfo)) {
            somelist[as.character(dataset[,1][k+y])]<-append(somelist[as.character(dataset[,1][k+y])],as.character(dataset[,3][k+y]))
        }
    }
}
```

It should be give output like:

```
somelist
$500x
[1] 9.07 8.24
$50x
[1] 11.64 12.82
$5x
[1] 23.6 35.17
```

But unfortunately I am getting following error:
  `number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`
Anybody knows why?
Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to make your own version of `split`? That is, `split(dataset$col1, dataset$col3)`

Comment: Yes something like that but I want to store those values in list based on index for further analysis

Comment: @Paul85 - `split` will name each list component by the splitting variable's unique values - in this case `col3` - I think it's exactly what you want.

Comment: @Gregor I think it's the other way around. split col3 on col1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically a ratification of comments. (I tried finding a duplicate ith a couple of different searches and failed, although I am pretty sure there must be one.)

```
> dat <- read.table(text="col1    col2    col3
+ 500x    high    9.07
+ 5x      low     23.6
+ 50x     medium  11.64
+ 500x    high    8.24
+ 5x      low     35.17
+ 50x     medium  12.82", head=T)
> split(dat$col3, dat$col1)
$`500x`
[1] 9.07 8.24

$`50x`
[1] 11.64 12.82

$`5x`
[1] 23.60 35.17
```